# How to share information between pages

Tags: maui

Before starting, as is stated in the title, I'm learning .NET MAUI and I'm very new in this.
My problem is that I can't find a way to share information from a page to a previous page.
What I'm trying to do is the following:

In the MainPage, have a button that once pressed, sends the user to another page, let's call it LoginPage, there, ask the user for his name, and after the input, redirect him to the previous page showing an "Hello {Name}, and welcome!"

MainPage code:

```
string Name = "";
string greetings = "";
async private void LogintBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                    
    }
    greetings = $"Welcome {Name}!";
    Greetinglbl.Text = greetings;
}
```

Log in code:

```
    public string name { get; set; }    
    private void btnRegister_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if  (ValidateName()==false) { return; };

    Navigation.PopAsync();
}

private bool ValidateName()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtRegistro.Text))
    {

        return false;
    }

    else
        return true;
}
```

Beside this, I don't know how to share information between these pages.
I have seen that a lot of devs use MVVM but I can't get a Beginners guide propperly, even watching the  .NET MAUI Beginners Guides from James Montemagno doesn't help me.

I've also tried using something like

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"LoginPage?Name={Name}");
```

that, for what I read is used to send data but don't know where to put it, plus triying to navigate with the same line throws an error (null).

Plus, most of the videos only shows how to send Data to the next Page, not the previous, and usually to a collection, and some of them import NuGet Packages that I don't see to be necessary in this project.

Comment: This is a commonly asked question. google `maui xamarin How to share information between pages`.

Comment: use shell navigation if you want to pass data when navigating back: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you could share the data through `Constructor`, here's the code snippet below for your reference.

**MainPage:**

*Xaml:*

```
<ScrollView> 
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">



            <Label Text="MainPage"></Label>

            <Button
              
                Text="To Login Page"
                Clicked="OnClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    public MainPage(string a)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Welcome Back",a,"OK");

    }

    private async void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
      }
```

**LoginPage:**

*Xaml:*

```
    <VerticalStackLayout> 

        <Label Text="LoginPage"></Label>
        
        <Entry x:Name="myentry"/>

        <Button
               
                Text="ToMain"
                Clicked="BackTo"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
public LoginPage() 
      {
            InitializeComponent();
   

  
      }

    private async void BackTo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage(myentry.Text));

    }
```

**Last but not least**, in your `App.xaml.cs`, use it like below:

```
MainPage = new NaviagtionPage(new MainPage())
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass data to your previous page, you can use the **same viewmodel to both pages**. You have to pass the viewmodel as a construct parameter to the next page. So, all variables will be available to both pages at the same time.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Button Text="Login"
         Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:LoginViewModel}}, Path=GoToLoginCommand}">
</Button>
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
[ObservableProperty]
string name;

public LoginViewModel() {
  // this is your default constructor
}

[RelayCommand]
public async void GoToLogin()
{
   //your command to the login page
   //pass your current view model to the page

   await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage(this));
}
```

Loginpage.xaml

```
<Entry
     EntryText="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

LoginPage.cs code behind:

```
public RoomFeaturesPage(LoginViewModel viewmodel)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = viewmodel;
}
```