# Maui MVVM , Problem with test app to get data from login API and pass FullName to MainPage after login , FullName=null out the ViewModel

Tags: testing, mvvm, binding, maui

1- I create an API by MVC to get

```
string MaUserName,
    string MaPassword,
    int MaId,
    int MaStatus,
    string MaFullName
```

**It works fine with Postman and swagger**

2- I create a Project that have

- Model>        `Manager.cs`
  *ViewModel>        `LoginVM.cs`
  *Statrup page>        `LoginPage.xaml`
  *View>        `MainPage.xaml`

and

```
BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

When I entered username and password the

```
public async Task<int> ExecuteLoginCommand(string username, string password)
```

go to MainPage after success by this code, is ok.

My API receive Username, Password and returned ID of this user  -- it works fine.

I have other method in API receive ID and returned all date of this id
when I send id to this method I received all information as a string.
By JSON converter
I get `MaFullName` from it - ok.

after end

```
   public async Task<int> ExecuteLoginCommand(string username, string password)
```

**all value of Model>Manager = null - this is problem**

I'll show all the code

```
public partial class Manager
{
    public int MaId { get; set; }
    public string MaUsername { get; set; } = null!;
    public string MaPassword { get; set; }
    public string MaFullname { get; set; }
    public int? MaStatus { get; set; }
}
```

```
 public partial class LoginVM : BaseViewModel
 {
     private string _username;
     private string _password;
     private string _fullname ;
     private bool _isUsernameValid;
     private bool _isPasswordValid;
     public int id = 0;
     private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
     public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
     public string Username
     {
         get => _username;
         set => SetProperty(ref _username, value);
     }
     public string Password
     {
         get => _password;
         set => SetProperty(ref _password, value);
     }
     public bool IsUsernameValid
     {
         get { return _isUsernameValid; }
         set
         {
             if (_isUsernameValid != value)
             {
                 _isUsernameValid = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged();
             }
         }
     }
     public bool isPasswordValid
     {
         get { return _isPasswordValid; }
         set
         {
             if (_isPasswordValid != value)
             {
                 _isPasswordValid = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged();
             }
         }
     }
     public string MaFullname
         
     {
         get => _fullname ?? "Error";
         set
         {
             if (_fullname != value)
             {
                 _fullname = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged();
             }
         }
     }
     public LoginVM()
     {
         _httpClient = new HttpClient();
         LoginCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoginCommand(Username, Password));
     }
     // check user and password
     public async Task<int> ExecuteLoginCommand(string username, string password)
     {

         HttpResponseMessage responseu = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Managers/GetManagersu/" + username + "," + password);
         int isUsernameValid = await responseu.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int>();
         if (responseu.IsSuccessStatusCode && isUsernameValid != 0)
         {
             id = isUsernameValid;
             HttpResponseMessage responseid = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Managers/" + id);
             string jsonfullname = await responseid.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             Manager manager = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);
             _fullname = manager.MaFullname;
             Console.WriteLine(MaFullname);
             await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//MainPage");
             return (isUsernameValid);
         }
         else
         {
             return 0;
         }
     } // end excutedlogincommand
 }
```

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));


    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value)) return false;
        backingField = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

RUN this app, LoginPage
IMG-1
[image: Image 1]

after login
IMG-2
[image: Image 2]
but there is "Error" from this line:

```
 public string MaFullname
 {
     get => _fullname ?? "Error";
```

I should be see "My Full Name" like pic.

IMG-3
[image: Image 3]
IMG-4
[image: Image 4]
IMG-5
[image: Image 5]
IMG-6
[image: Image 6]

1. I tried with ChatGPT but no solutions for this.
2. set a static value after the `ExecuteLoginCommand()`, it work
3. check my API and received `MaFullName`

Update code

Before run this line
[1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX9xa.png)

after run this line By F10
[2]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MexdX.png)

at same time
[3]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qdk9.png)

after F10*2   ,  whene exit from `ExecuteLoginCommand`
[4]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Xkk.png)

Comment: you are not assigning the value of this expression `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);` to anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share information between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73874475/how-to-share-information-between-pages)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (responseu.IsSuccessStatusCode && isUsernameValid != 0)
         {
             id = isUsernameValid;
             HttpResponseMessage responseid = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Managers/" + id);
             string jsonfullname = await responseid.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);
             // _fullname = manager.MaFullname;
             Console.WriteLine(MaFullname);
             await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//MainPage");
             return (isUsernameValid);
         }
```

From above code you shared, we could find that you want to deserialize Object by using code `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);`,but you didn't assign the result to any variable, such as an instance of the class `Manager` or assign it to variable `public string MaFullname` in your `LoginVM`.

So, you will not get the right value of `MaFullname` in `LoginVM.cs` by code `Console.WriteLine(MaFullname);`.

You can refer to the following code to Deserialize Object:

```
 //code snippet
   object obj=  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);

   if (obj != null && obj is Manager)
   {
      Manager item = obj as Manager;

       MaFullname = item.MaFullname;
   }
```

**Updated:**

> ```
>          Manager manager = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);
>          _fullname = manager.MaFullname;
> ```

Please replace code

```
  _fullname = manager.MaFullname
```

with:

```
  MaFullname = item.MaFullname;
```

Comment: I tried
// Manager manager = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);
//_fullname = manager.MaFullname;
object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);
if (obj != null && obj is Manager)
{
    Manager item = obj as Manager;
    MaFullname = item.MaFullname;
}
But same thing, prolem didnot solved.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to verify that it is behaving as expected?  Are you sure the json returned by the API can be deserialize into a Manager object?

Comment: whene i creat breakpoint at lines
 ``` Manager manager = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager>(jsonfullname);
_fullname = manager.MaFullname;```
I got _fullname "My FullName"  >> is ok
but after end the "            }
        } // end excutedlogincommand"
the _fullname = null

Comment: update my post , added new image for breakpoint result at _fullname = manager.MaFullName

Comment: Which page has the error?

Comment: No Errorr Masseges ,  i receved "My FullName" from API but print "Error" to Label in MainPage
i need to send an id no. to API and receve FullName , My API returnd JSON as a string ,  ande i used json converter >> is ok < but i can't print or save this value after converter method, check attachment images please .

Comment: you (I think, your description is very hard to understand) loading the data in PageA, then navigating to PageB, but are **NOT** passing the data between pages.   So the data is not displayed in PageB.  If this is the case, then see the link I posted above "How to Share Information Between Pages"

Comment: 1- Write username and password in IMG1.
2- Enter Login Buttom to check is user valid or not.
3- if login success go to MainPage + set Text of Label = MaFullName.ToString  -IMG2.
in IMG2 I shuld be see "My FullName" not  "Error" ,
`see IMG2` , Error is a word returned if value of MaFullName=null, see IMG4-6 , MaFullName not null whene the debug runnig inside the function `ExecuteLoginCommand` , but after end debuging this line ` } // end excutedlogincommand` , MaFullname become a null value :::: before end of ExcuteLogin  MaFullName="My FullName", after end of ExcutedLogin  MaFullName=null

Comment: `_fullname = manager.MaFullname;` this sets the private field, not the public property, and does NOT raise a property changed event.  You should assign to the public property, not the private field

Comment: what page is shown in IMG2?

Comment: Hi  @Alkhaldee, please check my updated reply at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Hi  Jessie Zhang , Thank you for updating , i update my code but same thing ,for more discruptions I attached 4 images after your update .

Comment: `after F10*2 , whene exit from ExecuteLoginCommand`   I don't quite understand this step, you mentioned earlier that after pressing F10, the data was normal.   `after F10*2` means do you press F10 again twice?

Comment: yes , press F10 twice

Comment: Why do you press twice? Do you want to debug multiple times, and is the data different each time?